# LOADERROR INSTALL COCAPODS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, flutter, ipad

I'm using Flutter in my app, when I went to build it showed that. I don't have Cocoapods, when I try to install with `SUDO GEM INSTALL COCOAPODS` the following message appears (I tried to update the GEM and it also didn't work)

[image]

Comment: Might need to install OpenSSL before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15305350/gem-install-fails-with-openssl-failure ?

Comment: Side note: copy/paste the contentt of your Terminal (not only screenshot), it might be much easier for others.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I already have OpenSSL installed, I tried the solution from the link above and the same screenshot message appeared

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14845481/cannot-load-such-file-openssl-loaderror Check the test in the answer for testing the existence of OpenSSL with Ruby (`ruby -ropenssl -e "puts :OK"`) else see the different posts.

Comment: I tried the above suggestion and it failed. I think I have to format the pc. But thanks. Anything I contact again